# How to view links between actions and permissions?

Tags: cleos, action, permissions

Currently I create permissions `perm*` for user `user`, and authorize it to push action `action*` to the code-containing account `code` like so:

```
cleos set account permission user perm* PUBLIC_KEY active
cleos set action permission user code action* perm*
```

I could easily imagine a scenario where complex permission system might be needed, where for example

- `perm1` can do `action1` and `action3`
- `perm2` can do `action2`
- `perm3` can do `action3`
- `perm4` can do everything `perm2` or `perm3` can
- ...

This can become quite hard to keep track of and I need a way to look up what actions need which permissions, but I have not found a way to do that in the documentation of cleos.

Is there any way I can verify which permissions are associated with which actions?